# Linking libcURL in Visual Studio 2008 Express

Tags: c++, visual-c++, libcurl

my first question here:

I am having trouble using libcURL in a c++ project. I don't even get it linked. I am using Windows XP and Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition.

So here is what I did:

1. Downloaded libcURL: curl-7.19.5-devel-mingw32.zip
2. Opened new commandline project in VC++
3. Include folders 'lib' and 'include' to my new project (maybe trivial but took me a while ;-)
4. in Properties->C/C++->General: Added folder 'include' to 'additional folders to include'
5. in Properties->Linker->General: Added folder 'lib' to 'additional folders with libraries'
6. in Properties->Linker->Input: Added additional dependencies: libcurl.a libcrypto.a libeay32.a libidn.a libssh2.a libssh2dll.a libssl32.a libssl.a libz.a libzdll.a ws2_32.lib wldap32.lib
7. in Properties->C/C++->Preprocessor: Added definition 'CURL_STATICLIB'
8. I unchecked 'Precompiled Headers' and made sure 'Multithreaded-DLL (/MD)' is used

Now I copied the example simple.c (from http://curl.haxx.se/lxr/source/docs/examples/simple.c) into my main project file. When I try to compile I get the following output:

```
Neues Erstellen gestartet: Projekt: curl_project, Konfiguration: Debug Win32
Die Zwischen- und Ausgabedateien für das Projekt "curl_project" mit der Konfiguration "Debug|Win32" werden gelöscht.
Kompilieren...
stdafx.cpp
Kompilieren...
curl_project.cpp
Manifest in Ressourcen wird kompiliert...
Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 6.1.6723.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
Verknüpfen...
libcurl.a(ftp.o) : error LNK2001: Nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "_strtoll".
libcurl.a(file.o) : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "_strtoll" in Funktion "_file_do".
libcurl.a(cookie.o) : error LNK2001: Nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "_strtoll".
libcurl.a(transfer.o) : error LNK2001: Nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "_strtoll".
libcurl.a(ssh.o) : error LNK2001: Nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "_strtoll".
libcurl.a(http.o) : error LNK2001: Nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "_strtoll".
libcurl.a(mprintf.o) : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "___umoddi3" in Funktion "_dprintf_formatf".
libcrypto.a(b_print.o) : error LNK2001: Nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "___umoddi3".
libcrypto.a(bn_word.o) : error LNK2001: Nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "___umoddi3".
libcurl.a(mprintf.o) : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "___udivdi3" in Funktion "_dprintf_formatf".
libcrypto.a(b_print.o) : error LNK2001: Nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "___udivdi3".
libcrypto.a(e_atalla.o) : error LNK2001: Nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "__alloca".
libcrypto.a(eng_padlock.o) : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "__alloca" in Funktion "_ENGINE_load_padlock".
libcrypto.a(sha512.o) : error LNK2001: Nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "__alloca".
libcrypto.a(bn_prime.o) : error LNK2001: Nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "__alloca".
libcurl.a(mprintf.o) : error LNK2001: Nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "__alloca".
libcurl.a(formdata.o) : error LNK2001: Nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "__alloca".
libcrypto.a(err_prn.o) : error LNK2001: Nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "__alloca".
libcrypto.a(cryptlib.o) : error LNK2001: Nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "__alloca".
libcurl.a(progress.o) : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "___divdi3" in Funktion "_time2str".
libssh2.a(scp.o) : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "_snprintf" in Funktion "_libssh2_scp_send_ex".
C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Punkx\Eigene Dateien\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\curl_project\Debug\curl_project.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 6 nicht aufgelöste externe Verweise.
Das Buildprotokoll wurde unter "file://c:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Punkx\Eigene Dateien\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\curl_project\curl_project\Debug\BuildLog.htm" gespeichert.
curl_project - 22 Fehler, 0 Warnung(en)
========== Alles neu erstellen: 0 erfolgreich, Fehler bei 1, 0 übersprungen ==========
```

---

Can someone see, what I have forgotten or where the problem is? I am a C++ Beginner, so it could be something trival...
Thx for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using MinGW libraries with the Visual C++ compiler.  Use the correct binary package and/or build it yourself.

If you're using Visual C++, you shouldn't be dealing with .a files but only with .lib.

Comment: Can you provide a description of how to set these up once you have them?